# Distributed Search Issues - Max number of local indexes

Tags: sphinx

I'm running 1.10-beta and have a distributed index setup. There are 4 base chunks and 4
delta chunks making the dist index look like this:

```
index dist_idx
{
        type = distributed
        local = b_0
        local = b_1
        local = b_2
        local = b_3
        local = d_0
        local = d_1
        local = d_2
        local = d_3
}
```

Each chunk is a mod on the unique id (id MOD 4). My problem is only the first 7 are used.
In my test case I have the following data:

```
b_0 = 4 8
b_1 = 5
b_2 = 2 6
b_3 = 3 7
d_1 = 1
```

If I change the dist index to only have those 5 and search against dist_idx all 8 records
come back, but, if I search against it as I first described it only 2-8 return.

Does anyone have any ideas! I don't want to combine my delta's really although it would
probably work.

REF: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=5163